# Select control search on the basis of data fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

Currently I am using [Jquery Chosen Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in order to search the values written inside a search box and it works very well in case I want to search on the basis of the text written inside the `option` tag. i.e. as shown in the figure:

[image: Chosen Plugin demo]

But what I want to achieve is search on the multiple basis i.e. on the basis of the text written inside the `option` tag as well as the data attributes of the option tag i.e.

[image: Anyother plugin]

For example in the above figure I may be able to search `Debitors` either by typing `Debitors` directly or by typing the `data-phone`'s value i.e.`0321-111111`. I've searched the `chosen` plugin's documentation for the possibility to search on the basis of multiple values but, as much as I know, there wasn't any functionality provided by it.

Now what I'd like to ask is, Is there any jQuery plugin providing this multisearch functionality that you may know of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) Jquery plugin that allows the custom matcher for the searching. i.e. You can define whatever you want plugin's search to search.